# Hide and unhide selected sheets in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Problem:
I would like to have the ability to hide and unhide selected (multiple) sheets by a form

Available Resource:
There many available resources that show how to unhide and hide all sheets at one but not flexible

Explain:

[image]

Because sheet5 is hidden checkbox corresponds to Sheet5 is checked.

Logic/approach:

- Get all of the sheets' name include hided ones and bind them to Labels, check if it is hide or unhide and bind it to checkbox.

Label and Checkbox are created automatically, lable and checkbox is somehow linked to each other so the program knows which sheets to hide and to unhide.

- write the code to check whether a checkbox changes its status between selected/unselected.

Comment: Also are you doing this in VB.Net/C#?

Comment: Thank you for asking. I am trying to do it in VBA of excel. The winform is just for explaining purpose: [1]I have learned how to hide and unhide sheet. [2] I have trouble with automatic create label and checkbox

Comment: Do you want to create all those controls at runtime? Or do you want to have those controls beforehand and simply enable/disable them based on whether the sheet is visible or not?

Comment: I would like to have the list when I run the form/macro. [1]The Form Display All Sheets (There are possible of 300sheets at max). [2]If the sheet is unhide make the checkbox is selected, if it is hide make the checkbox is unselected. [3]If I click on the selected ones - unhide, if I click on the unselected - hide.

Comment: VBA is the one I want, no VB. Net, I only use it for explanation

Comment: `There are possible of 300sheets at max` In that case I suggest using a listbox or a combobox. :)

Comment: A list box is fine. The main problem is the ability to hide and unhide certain. I guess if using the list box the will be two columns: 1 for the name of sheets, one to indicates the status hide/unhide.  The behavior is if I click on the row than it changes status.

Comment: Status update: currently I am able to populate the all of the sheets'name and their status (hide/unhide) to two columns on listbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I am able to do the work. It is probably not good code, but it works.

[image]

```
Private Sub btListAllSheets_Click()

    With Me.ListBox1

    .Clear
    .ColumnHeads = True
    .ColumnCount = 2
    Dim status As String

    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        If Sheets(i).Visible = xlSheetHidden Then
           status = "Invisible"
        Else
           status = "Visible"
        End If

    ListBox1.AddItem (Sheets(i).Name)
    ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListCount - 1, 1) = status

    Next i
    End With

End Sub

Private Sub bt_hideunhideselectedsheet_Click()

    Dim str As String
    str = Me.ListBox1.Column(1, Me.ListBox1.ListIndex)

    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    If Sh.Name = Me.ListBox1.Value And str = "Visible" Then    
        Sh.Visible = False   
    ElseIf Sh.Name = Me.ListBox1.Value And str = "Invisible" Then    
        Sh.Visible = True
    End If

    Next Sh

End Sub
```